# Strange error updating PHP code in a node

Tags: nodes

I have a 'Basic Page' node that contains PHP code which returns the following error, when I edit and save it:

> Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.

I believe it is not the real error; if I edit anything but the code, I don't get any error.

What I do is changing `<?php if (user_is_logged_in()): ?>` to `<?php if (user_is_logged_in() && (inarray('approved user', $GLOBALS['user']->roles)))): ?>`.

I'm pretty positive the code is right; the PHP filter is enabled, and the administrator user is the only user who can use it. I'm not really sure what else could be the issue.

Comment: As side comment, in Drupal you normally don't check if the user has a specific role, but if the user has a specific permission, which means you normally call [user_access()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_access/7).

Comment: @kiamlaluno I think you mean [`user_access()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_access/7). `user_permission()` is the `user` module's implementation of `hook_permission()`

Comment: Whoops, you are right. I edited my comment. `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`inarray()` isn't a PHP function, you're probably looking for [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) :)

The error you're getting is probably masking the internal `Call to undefined function inarray()` exception that would be thrown.

**EDIT**

You also have one too many closing parentheses at the moment, I'd recommend separating out your code to make it cleaner:

```
<?php

$has_required_role = in_array('approved user', $GLOBALS['user']->roles);
if (user_is_logged_in() && $has_required_role):
  // Do something
endif;

?>
```

Comment: no, i still get the same with in_array().

Comment: @pandabrand Please check the updated answer

Comment: nope, still the same response

Comment: ok, that was weird I had to take out the space in the if statement  `(user_is_logged_in()&&$has_required_role)`  worked, strange.